# using kendo ui grid and backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, kendo-ui

i'm using the kendo ui grid on my backbone application. i used this codes.

https://github.com/telerik/kendo-backbone

But i'm having this error on firebug.

```
invalid 'instanceof' operand backboneModel
if (!(model instanceof backboneModel)) {
```

I have this code.

cartlistview.js

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'kendo',
  'model/cart_model',
  'model/invoice_model',
  'model/input_model',
  'collection/cart_collection',
  'collection/invoice_detail_collection',
  'collection/invoice_collection',
  'text!templates/cart/cartlist.html'
 ], function($, _, Backbone, kendoGrid, Cart, Invoice, Input, CartCollection, InvoiceDetailCollection, InvoiceCollection, CartListTemplate){

var Model = kendo.data.Model,
    ObservableArray = kendo.data.ObservableArray;

function wrapBackboneModel(backboneModel, fields) {
    return Model.define({
        fields: fields,
        init: function(model) {
            if (!(model instanceof backboneModel)) {
                model = new backboneModel(model);
            }

            Model.fn.init.call(this, model.toJSON());
            this.backbone = model;
        },
        set: function(field, value) {
            Model.fn.set.call(this, field, value);

            this.backbone.set(field, value);
        }
    });
}

function wrapBackboneCollection(model) {
    return ObservableArray.extend( {
        init: function(collection) {
            ObservableArray.fn.init.call(this, collection.models, model);

            this.collection = collection;
        },

        splice: function(index, howMany) {
            var itemsToInsert, removedItemx, idx, length;

            itemsToInsert = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2);

            removedItems = kendo.data.ObservableArray.fn.splice.apply(this, arguments);

            if (removedItems.length) {
                for (idx = 0, length = removedItems.length; idx < length; idx++) {
                    this.collection.remove(removedItems[idx].backbone);
                }
            }

            if (itemsToInsert.length) {
                for (idx = 0, length = itemsToInsert.length; idx < length; idx++) {
                    this.collection.unshift(itemsToInsert[idx].backbone);
                }
            }

            return removedItems;
        }
    });
}

kendobackboneCollection = wrapBackboneCollection;
kendobackboneModel = wrapBackboneModel;

   var CartListView = Backbone.View.extend({
   el: $("#cartContainer"),
   events:{
    "click .k-grid-save-changes"  : "save"
   },
   initialize: function(){
   CartCollection.bind("add", this.render, this);
   CartCollection.bind("change:QuantityOrdered", this.render, this);
   CartCollection.bind("change:ExtPriceRate", this.render, this);
},
render: function(){
  $("#cartContainer").html(CartListTemplate);
  var CartWrapper = kendobackboneModel(cart, {
     ItemCode: { type: "string" },
     ItemDescription: { type: "string" },
     RetailPrice: { type: "string" },
     Qty: { type: "string" },
  });
  var CartCollectionWrapper = kendobackboneCollection(CartWrapper);
  this.$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    editable: true,
    toolbar: [{ name: "save", text: "Complete" }],
    columns: [
        {field: "ItemDescription", title: "ItemDescription"},
        {field: "QuantityOrdered", title: "Qty",width:80},
        {field: "SalesPriceRate", title: "UnitPrice"},
        {field: "ExtPriceRate", title: "ExtPrice"}
    ],
    dataSource: {
      schema: {model: CartWrapper},
      data: new CartCollectionWrapper(cartcollection),
     }
  });

},
save: function(){
    var input = new Input();
    var invoicecollection = new InvoiceCollection();
    var invoicedetail = new InvoiceDetailCollection();
    _.each(cartcollection.models, function(cart){
        invoicedetail.add( cart );
    });
    input.set({ "Invoices": invoicecollection.toJSON() });
    input.set({ "InvoiceDetails": invoicedetail });

    if( invoicedetail.length === 0){ 
        alert("Shopping Cart is Empty"); 
    }else{
        alert(JSON.stringify(input));
        input.save(input, {success: function(model, result){
            var InvoiceCode = result.InvoiceCode;
            alert("Transaction Complete., Invoice code:"+InvoiceCode);
        }});
        cartcollection.reset();
        invoicedetail.reset();
        this.render();
    }

}
 });
return new CartListView;
});
```

my Cart Collection

```
define([
'underscore',
'backbone',
'model/cart_model'
],function(_, Backbone, Cart){
var CartCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Cart,
  initialize: function(){

  }
});
return CartCollection;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occurs because backboneModel is undefined. Check this code:

```
var CartWrapper = kendobackboneModel(cart,
```

I don't see `cart` defined anywhere in your file. You probably need `Cart`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it may help you or not,  but try instead of this

`if (!(model instanceof backboneModel)) { 
       model = new backboneModel(model); 
   }`

write this

`if (!model instanceof kendo.data.Model) {
       model = new backboneModel(model);
   }`

**UDP**:

Basicly `instanceof` comparing object with it's class.. `is OBJECT instance of CLASS`.. your mistake was that you are comaring object to object.

Comment: i didn't really wrote the code. i used the one on the link. but anyway i tried your suggestion. Now it has an error stating backboneModel is not a constructor; model = new backboneModel(model);